# How to set up a neural network so that it have in output only 0 or 1?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have a dataset (it have 10000 rows):

> ```
>       0     1     2       3      4     ...   53      54      55        56     57
>  0  10309   0  402.64  263.65  134.99  ...  0.39  263.65  134.99  401.833548   0
>  1  10310   0  398.64  263.65  134.99  ...  0.39  263.65  134.99  401.833548   0
>  2  10311   0  398.64  263.65  134.99  ...  0.39  263.65  134.99  401.833548   0
>  3  10312   0  398.64  263.65  134.99  ...  0.39  263.65  134.99  401.833548   0
>  4  10313   0  403.64  263.65  134.99  ...  0.39  263.65  134.99  401.833548   0
> ```

I have to make a neural network that will predict the value of column # 1 (it can be 0 or 1).

I created a two-layer neural network.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
```

And got an output:

> [[-1.57625228e-03  1.61733944e-04 -1.49833616e-02  1.79843791e-03
>     -2.96636093e-02 -6.63164817e-03 -9.47585609e-03  5.64101897e-03
>      5.64101897e-03 -1.29007865e-02  5.64101897e-03  3.58308945e-03
>     -9.53195766e-02 -1.32898521e-02  5.22762071e-04  4.18396108e-03
>     -2.88559217e-02 -2.44860705e-02 -1.18804779e-02  7.53945857e-02
>     -2.02486850e-03 -2.17353478e-02 -7.60783181e-02 -5.02919555e-02
>      7.87826702e-02 -3.26374844e-02  6.09703511e-02  3.32313627e-02
>      1.42815514e-02  3.70703414e-02  5.64101897e-03  9.96760353e-02
>     -2.02211499e-01 -1.06276069e-02 -1.71094477e-01  6.36711642e-02
>     -9.27114673e-03 -8.05514529e-02 -1.24936230e-01 -9.09972191e-02
>     -9.61129889e-02 -9.41279978e-02 -9.14852545e-02 -1.23843096e-01
>     -4.96111661e-02 -7.75326695e-03 -3.41935158e-02 -6.24957904e-02
>     -3.43749672e-03 -6.50173202e-02  7.04494305e-04 -6.82023242e-02
>     -6.80137798e-02 -5.75559661e-02  3.78455073e-02 -4.41458300e-02
>     -3.51775438e-02 -1.93608720e-02 -7.32456967e-02 -5.12493961e-03
>     -3.92356515e-02 -3.91514003e-02 -5.93186915e-03 -7.00767413e-02
>     -4.91175205e-02 -3.92843783e-02 -1.70611106e-02 -6.61014542e-02
>     -1.65037028e-02 -3.93037796e-02 -3.91289964e-02 -1.61894206e-02
>     -3.40123251e-02 -2.89186090e-03  3.31846252e-03 -5.55966273e-02
>      3.67479622e-02 -6.71871677e-02 -1.06477588e-01 -1.19096853e-01
>      3.82361114e-02 -5.07725924e-02  3.69399088e-03  4.46796566e-02
>     -2.69809160e-02  3.70123982e-02  1.08064897e-03 -3.58955748e-03
>      8.01469535e-02  7.87181482e-02 -4.26483620e-03  4.88822088e-02
>      1.59037113e-02  5.56310862e-02  1.58798099e-02  1.58805288e-02
>     1.58808343e-02 -2.12251153e-02  1.56732872e-02  1.39700407e-02]]

But I had to get something like:

> 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is fine. A Neural Network for a binary classification doesn't return "clean", integer outputs. A good binary classifier is a model that would predict this one-hot encoded vector:

```
[0, 1]
```

as:

```
[0.00001, 0.99999]
```

If you put a **softmax** layer at the bottom, you could interpret those values as "the probability of being 0 or 1".

Comment: @Neel
I entered: 
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(pred, axis=None, name=None, dim=None)
    print("Predicted value:\n", pred, end=' ')
And then instead of 0 and 1 I got:
    Predicted value of churned:
     Tensor("Softmax_7:0", shape=(100, 1), dtype=float64)

Comment: you need to add a layer with sigmoid activation. Sigmoid is what you need for binary classification tasks. Softmax is for multiclass classification (a generalization of Sigmoid). You have to put it *inside* the neural Network architecture.

Comment: Take a look at how I did this binary classification tasks. It's written in TensorFlow 2.0, which relies on the Keras syntax:

https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0_01_basic_Classifier.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

For a binary outcome, you need sigmoid activation function. Softmax provides a number between (0,1) which can easily be transformed to binary prediction.

### For multiclass classification

If your classification problem has more than 2 classes, your final layer need to have as many neurons as the number of classes. The activation function will still be sigmoid, however you will need to use a softmax on top of the outcome of the final layer to get the actual classes as prediction